# Angular 5 Router.Переход на этот же адрес

Tags: angular2

привет не большая проблема.
[image: картинка чтобы было понятнее]

4 ссылки генерируется  в цикле.

```
<a [routerLink]="['bydata', d]" *ngFor="let d of data">
            <li>{{d}}</li>
          </a>
```

Так вот проблема в том что  с
`http://localhost:4200/` он переходит на `http://localhost:4200/bydata/1` все ок

но если попробовать перейти с

```
http://localhost:4200/bydata/параметр
```

на любой другой

```
http://localhost:4200/bydata/параметр2
```

то не переходит.
Я так понимаю потомучто это уже похожий адрес но ведь параметр меняется.
Как верно сделать.

Answer (score 0):

проблема решена

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.genre = params['genre'];
      this.startLoad();
    });
  }
```

отслеживание изменение параметра и что то делаем если он изменился